# (PHPUnit) Is it possible to test mkdir, tempnam, realpath and move_uploaded_file?

Tags: php, phpunit, vfs

I'm making a test for a **File System** and I wanted to know if is possible to test if some functions are functional.

I'm using [vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream) for the most of them, but this virtual file system doesn't work with some functionality of the File System.

I succeeded to test:

- [chmod( )](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.chmod.php)
- [unlink( )](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unlink.php)
- [dirname( )](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.dirname.php)
- [basename( )](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.basename.php)

See an example:

```
public function unlink($file) {

        return unlink($file);
    }
```

The unit test:

```
public function setUp() {
        $this->fileSystem = new FileSystem();

        // Creates my Virtual File System 
        $tree = array('library' => array('test.txt' => 'conteudo do arquivo'));
        $home = vfsStream::setup("home", '', $tree);
    }

public function testUnlink() {
        $this->assertTrue($this->fileSystem->unlink(vfsStream::url('home/library/test.txt')));
    }
```

However, I still got 4 more functions that I need to test and I don't know if I actually can do this in PHPUnit.

As you can see, all of them are from PHP (like [`unlink( )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)), but I also modified them to handle some errors properly, even though my priority now is to test if the basic function of the PHP is functional in my code.

The functions I don't know how to test are:

- [mkdir( )](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mkdir.php)
- [tempnam( )](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.tempnam.php)
- [realpath( )](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.realpath.php)
- [move_uploaded_file( )](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Someone know how to make an unit test for any of the functions above?

Comment: as for mkdir() cant you just create a directory and check for return as mkdir gives you a boolean return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 of the 4 you mentioned are easy enough to write simple tests for:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
 public function mkdirWorksAsExpected()
 {
     $tmp_dir = 'mkdirtest';

     if (is_dir($tmp_dir)) {
         rmdir($tmp_dir);
     }

     mkdir($tmp_dir);
     $this->assertTrue(is_dir($tmp_dir));
 }

 /**
  * @test
  */
 public function tempnamWorksAsExpected()
 {
     $tmp_dir = 'tempnamtest';
     $filename = tempnam($tmp_dir, 'test');

     $this->assertTrue(file_exists($filename));
     unlink($filename);
 }

 /**
  * @test
  */
  public function realpathWorksAsExpected()
  {
      $filename = tempnam('/tmp', 'test');
      $this->assertEquals($filename, realpath($filename));
      unlink($filename);
  }
```

Testing move_uploaded_file() would require you to actually simulate the uploading of a file using something like Guzzle and an end point. I don't think manipulating the contents of $_POST is enough, but I haven't tried it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I guess now is really not viable to find other solution (I didn't want to create a real directory or file), but as Vfs Stream doesn't work for this functions, I'll make it simple as this. Thank you, Chris! I'm going to search for a way to test the move_uploaded_file function also and I'll update it in my question.